# Why does my setInterval loop go another round before exiting even though I have the termination in the beginning

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry for gore title.. But if you take a look at this code

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
            if (start == false || score_met == true) {
                clearInterval(interval);
            }

            // call generation again for each generation, passing in the previous generations best offspring
            best_offspring = generation(best_offspring, characters, target_text, mutation_rate, amount_offspring);
            document.getElementById("output_text").value = best_offspring;
            document.getElementById("generations").value = generations;
            }, delay);
    });
```

This will loop untill the score is met or if I change the value of `start`. My reset button code looks like this

```
        //resets
    $( "#reset" ).click(function() {
            start = false;
            score_met = false;
            generations = 0;
            best_offspring = "";

            document.getElementById("start_text").value = "";
            document.getElementById("characters").value = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            document.getElementById("target_text").value = "methinks it is like a weasel";
            document.getElementById("output_text").value = "";
            document.getElementById("mutation_rate").value = 5;
            document.getElementById("amount_offspring").value = 100;
            document.getElementById("delay").value = 50;
        });
    });
```

So when I click reset my loop should end right? But it seems like it does another loop before it terminates. Why is that? I was thinking that you could do something like

`$( interval ).ready(function() {...});`

but then Im quite unsure what to put instead of interval there.

Comment: Simply do `clearInterval(interval); return;` to exit the function after clearing. Clearing prevents the _next_ call, it will still continue the _current_ call until it terminates. You could also wrap the rest of your code in an `else`, which would also skip the rest of the code and termintate the function.

Comment: @somethinghere seems to work! thx.

Answer (score 3):

Explaining your code.

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
        if (start == false || score_met == true) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }

        // call generation again for each generation, passing in the previous generations best offspring
        best_offspring = generation(best_offspring, characters, target_text, mutation_rate, amount_offspring);
        document.getElementById("output_text").value = best_offspring;
        document.getElementById("generations").value = generations;
        }, delay);
```

You are clearing the interval that is fine, But `this part of code has already started executing`, so `the part of the code after if will execute at this moment`. So put it inside a else and you must be fine.

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
        if (start == false || score_met == true) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        else{
          // call generation again for each generation, passing in the previous generations best offspring
          // your stuff here
         }           
        }, delay);
```

Comment: These ending braces are not correct I think: `});` (they dont seem to match up with any opening code) - but this works. You could also use `return`.

Comment: @somethinghere yes you are right, using return will also work.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do `clearInterval(interval); return;` to exit the function after clearing. Clearing prevents the *next* call, it will still continue the *current* call until it terminates:

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    if (start == false || score_met == true) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        return;
    }
    /* ... */
}, 1000);
```

You could also wrap the rest of your code in an `else`, which would also skip the rest of the code and terminate the function naturally.